# How to rename a field managed by Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I use Lombok quite a lot with @Data annotation. But sometimes I need to rename a field. My IDE (Eclipse) let me rename the field, but all references are not updated which results in a lot of errors and also lots of manual work to change the refernces to the new field name.
Is there any way to rename a field that automatically renames the references as well ?

thanks for any hints!
Thorsten

Comment: Use Eclipse to generate the getter and setter for the property you're about to rename, using `Source` > `Generate Getters and Setters...`. Then use Eclipse to rename the methods, using `Refactor` > `Rename...`. When done, delete the getter and setter again, so `@Data` can do it.

Comment: Yes, but if I use e.g. @Data annotation, Eclipse won't let me create getter/setter, because it's says getter/setter are already created (the ones created by Lombok).

Comment: You did follow the eclipse setup guide [here](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse), right? I'm surprised it doesn't also rename the references to getters and setters, because the Lombok plugin for IntelliJ IDEA _does_ do that. Time to consider switching IDEs :-D

Comment: @user1119859 So you also temporarily add `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` to the field in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming should work in later versions of lombok, there has been some issues lately [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r15HI.png).

On the field you want to rename press `Alt+Shift+R` (alternatively find a field in Project explorer a select rename)

[image: fieldOptions]

Select *options*
[image]

and make sure you select all options you want to be performed e.g. updating references in JavaDoc or renaming getters and setters.

Hit the OK or Preview!

--

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r15HI.png) https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1758

Answer (score 1):

Use AccessLevel.NONE

```
        @Getter(lombok.AccessLevel.NONE)
        Long accountForFees;
        
        public Long getAccountForFees() {
            return accountForFees;
        }
```

Now you can use IDE to rename method.